# Finding human-readable files on Unix

Tags: linux, find, human-readable

I'd like to find human-readable files on my Linux machine without a file extension constraint. Those files should be readable by humans using a text editor, for example: text, configuration, HTML, and source code files.

Is there a way to filter and locate them?

Comment: The `file` utility is pretty good at determining the type of content in a file.  Perhaps you could use this and filter files based on its output.

Comment: AFAIK only Windows trusts file extension. UNIX-like OSs use `file`. Anyway, you have to define "human readable".

Comment: How precisely does this need to be? And are you looking for EVERY file in the system, or just in a selected part of the system? What if the system has umpteen terabytes of disks attached, is it acceptable to wait for several hours (because that's how long it takes to actually read all the files)?

Comment: Also, would for example a PDF be considered human readable, or not? What about "postscript"? What about contents in a mail-folder? What about .zip, .tar, .gz, .bz, or .xz files? If those are just containers for text files, does that count?

Comment: i will be searching in a directory with size of, let us a say, 5 GB. to define human-readable on examples; pdf, tar.gz, an thunderbird mail file, open office files etc are not-readable. we should read files by more utility or vi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix))* and *[file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file)* are your friends here:

```
find /dir/to/search -type f -exec sh -c 'file -b {} | grep text &>/dev/null' \; -print
```

This will find any files (NOTE: it will not find symlinks directories sockets, etc., only regular files) in */dir/to/search* and run sh -c 'file -b {} | grep text &>/dev/null' ; which looks at the type of file and looks for text in the description. If this returns true (i.e., text is in the line) then it prints the filename.

NOTE: using the -b flag to file means that the filename is not printed and therefore cannot create any issues with the *grep*. E.g., without the `-b` flag the binary file gettext would erroneously be detected as a textfile.

For example,

```
root@osdevel-pete# find /bin -exec sh -c 'file -b {} |  grep text &>/dev/null' \; -print
/bin/gunzip
/bin/svnshell.sh
/bin/unicode_stop
/bin/unicode_start
/bin/zcat
/bin/redhat_lsb_init
root@osdevel-pete# find /bin -type f -name *text*
/bin/gettext
```

If you want to look in compressed files use the `--uncompress` flag to file. For more information and flags to file see [man file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file).

Comment: I am new to the unix-like ecosystem. Why are you using "&" at the end of your `grep`? My understanding is that this will make grep run asynchronously. Will this still give the exit status to `find`? Why would one do that? Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @JesseEmond: The command doesn't actually contain a `&` token which would put the job in the background, it contains a `&>` token which causes redirection of both stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 25):

Use:

`find /dir/to/search -type f | xargs file | grep text`

`find` will give you a list of files.

`xargs file` will run the `file` command on each of the lines from the piped input.

Comment: And for files with *funny* names:  `find /dir/to/search -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep text` ... **funny**? Embedded spaces, parenthesis, brackets, braces, ...

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, too:

```
file_info=`file "$file_name"` # First reading the file info string which should have the words "ASCII" or "Unicode" if it's a readable file

if grep -q -i -e "ASCII" -e "Unicode"<<< "$file_info"; then
    echo "file is readable"
fi
```