# Viewing all directories that are world readable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I want to write a shell script that will show me which users home directories are world readable so I can easily see directories I have access to. I was trying to figure out how to do this. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated!

Comment: For system commands like this, you might have better luck over at SuperUser.SE

Comment: You may try `find` with `perm` option, and ask on SuperUser if you still have problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find -perm` like this:

```
find /base/path -type d -perm +o+r
```

**`+o+r` will only list directories with word (others) read bit on.**

Answer (score 0):

have you checked this

```
find /dir/to/search -type f -exec sh -c 'file -b {} | grep text &>/dev/null' \; -print
```

From [Finding human-readable files on unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505218/finding-human-readable-files-on-unix)

Answer (score -2):

Use this command

```
ll /path/to/your/dirextory/ | grep ^d......r..
```

This will give you the directories will everyone has permission to read.

Comment: -1 `ll` is not a standard command, and parsing the output of `ls` is poor practice.

Comment: @triplee, I agree that `ll` ia not a standard command, but `ls` is described in the POSIX specification, so don't see why parsing its output would be poor practice, as long as it is done correctly (which is not the case here)

Comment: @Scrutinizer http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks for the link and pointing out that file names can contain newline characters! I have never come across a file name with newlines, so for command line work, one can probably get away with it, but for production shell scripts, that is a different matter, I agree..